# Match the hash when hash is inserted as Vec<u8>

Tags: rust

```
use sha3::{Digest, Keccak256};


fn reveal_vote(mut voter_id: Vec<u8>, mut phrase: Vec<u8>, vote_commit: Vec<u8>) {

    let mut hyphen_vec = "-".as_bytes().to_vec();
    voter_id.append(&mut hyphen_vec);
    voter_id.append(&mut phrase);
    let vote_bytes: &[u8] = &voter_id;
    let mut hasher = Keccak256::new();
    hasher.update(vote_bytes);
    let result = hasher.finalize();
    let vote_commit_bytes: &[u8] = &vote_commit;

    if &result[..] == vote_commit_bytes {
        println!("Data matched");
    } else {
        println!("data mismatched")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let vote_commit_string = "1-abcdef".as_bytes().to_vec();
    let mut hasher = Keccak256::new();
    hasher.update(vote_commit_string);
    let result = hasher.finalize();
    let commit = format!("{:x}", result); // e2a18e9b74f228590ca8c563cecfc58c28455b2dde25b4bbdc663e99e791f47c
    let commit_vec = commit.as_bytes().to_vec();
    println!("commit: {:?}", commit);
    reveal_vote("1".as_bytes().to_vec(), "abcdef".as_bytes().to_vec(), commit_vec);
}
```

Want to check the hash matches, but both hash and string are in Vec<u8>,
but `&result[..] == vote_commit_bytes` doesnot match. How to check the equality?
https://docs.rs/sha3/0.9.1/sha3/

Comment: "doesnot work" is not a problem description. What happens when you try it? Why is that wrong?

Comment: It doesn't match, I am using wrong equality it seems.

Answer (score 2):

There is no equality, because apparently the `format!()` macro alters the data in some way (which I think is not totally unexpected).

The [`{:x}`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#formatting-traits) formatting option, formats the data as:

> Debug with lower-case hexadecimal integers

so that is why those representations are not equal.

If you format both hash results in your code, it works as expected:

```rust
use sha3::{Digest, Keccak256};


fn reveal_vote(mut voter_id: Vec<u8>, mut phrase: Vec<u8>, vote_commit: Vec<u8>) {

    let mut hyphen_vec = "-".as_bytes().to_vec();
    voter_id.append(&mut hyphen_vec);
    voter_id.append(&mut phrase);
    let vote_bytes: &[u8] = &voter_id;
    let mut hasher = Keccak256::new();
    hasher.update(vote_bytes);
    let result = hasher.finalize();
    let vote_commit_bytes: &[u8] = &vote_commit;

    let commit = format!("{:x}", result); // e2a18e9b74f228590ca8c563cecfc58c28455b2dde25b4bbdc663e99e791f47c

    if commit.as_bytes().to_vec() == vote_commit_bytes {
        println!("Data matched");
    } else {
        println!("data mismatched")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let vote_commit_string = "1-abcdef".as_bytes().to_vec();
    let mut hasher = Keccak256::new();
    hasher.update(vote_commit_string);
    let result = hasher.finalize();
    let commit = format!("{:x}", result); // e2a18e9b74f228590ca8c563cecfc58c28455b2dde25b4bbdc663e99e791f47c
    let commit_vec = commit.as_bytes().to_vec();
    println!("commit: {:?}", commit);
    reveal_vote("1".as_bytes().to_vec(), "abcdef".as_bytes().to_vec(), commit_vec);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, old question, solved it using hex

```
use sha3::{Digest, Keccak256};
use hex;


fn reveal_vote(mut voter_id: Vec<u8>, mut phrase: Vec<u8>, vote_commit: Vec<u8>) {

    let mut hyphen_vec = "-".as_bytes().to_vec();
    voter_id.append(&mut hyphen_vec);
    voter_id.append(&mut phrase);
    let vote_bytes: &[u8] = &voter_id;
    let mut hasher = Keccak256::new();
    hasher.update(vote_bytes);
    let result = hasher.finalize();    
    if  hex::encode(result).as_bytes().to_vec() == vote_commit {
        println!("Data matched");
    } else {
        println!("data mismatched")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let vote_commit_string = "1-abcdef".as_bytes().to_vec();
    let mut hasher = Keccak256::new();
    hasher.update(vote_commit_string);
    let result = hasher.finalize();
    println!("{:?}", result);
    println!("{:?}", &result[..]);
    let commit = format!("{:x}", result); // e2a18e9b74f228590ca8c563cecfc58c28455b2dde25b4bbdc663e99e791f47c
    let commit_vec = commit.as_bytes().to_vec();
    // println!("commit: {:?}", commit);
    println!("commit_vec: {:?}", commit_vec);
    reveal_vote("1".as_bytes().to_vec(), "abcdef".as_bytes().to_vec(), commit_vec);
}
```